# Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member ''

Tags: swift

For school, I am making an app about the Holocaust.  I need to display info about the camps on a detailViewController, but it isn't working.  I am able to access the variable's "name" value (sorry if my terminology is wrong), but nothing else.  Other posts aren't in Swift or don't relate to my specific issue, so I can't find a solution.

Here is the code from the class that creates the variable type:

```
class DeathCamp: NSObject {

var name:String = ""
var locationCountry:String = ""
var jewishDeathCount:Int = 0
init(name:String, locationCountry:String, jewishDeathCount:Int){
    self.name = name
    self.locationCountry = locationCountry
    self.jewishDeathCount = jewishDeathCount
}



}
```

Here is the code where the detail items are set to the arrays:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)     {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let deathCampNewObject = deathCampArray[indexPath.row]
            let countryDeathNewObject = countryArray[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItemDeath = deathCampNewObject
            controller.detailItemCountry = countryDeathNewObject
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}
```

In response to a suggestion from a comment, here is my entire code for the DetailViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var percentageJewsKilled: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var jewsKilled: UILabel!
let masterViewController = MasterViewController()

var detailItemDeath: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view.
        self.configureView()
    }
}
var detailItemCountry: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view.
        self.configureView()

    }
}

func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let detail = self.detailItemDeath {
        if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
            label.text = detailItemDeath?.name
        }
        if let label = self.jewsKilled {
            label.text = "\(detailItemDeath?.jewishDeathCount)"
        }
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.configureView()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Without all the code, it's difficult to understand what is calling what. `configureView` belongs to what class? What calls it? Post the code for `DetailViewController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

`if let detail = self.detailItemDeath`

to:

`if let detail = self.detailItemDeath as? DeathCamp`

The code above attempts a **cast** of `detailItemDeath` to an object of  type `DeathCamp`.

Also change

`detailItemDeath?.name`

to:

`detailItemDeath.name`

You've already attempted an unwrap of `detailItemDeath` with the `if let` syntax, optional chaining is redundant and therefore erroneous.

And, I can't believe I missed this, rename `detailItemDeath` in `detailItemDeath.name` to `detail`!

Comment: I just changed that line of code, yet it still is giving me the same error.

Comment: @BenA.: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  When I do what you suggested, I get "Value of optional type 'AnyObject?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

Comment: @BenA.: Updated yet again.

Comment: I renamed what you suggested for the .name and the .jewishDeathCount, and it worked!  Thank you.